# Python TikTokAPI ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, api, tiktok

Hello in the following code i get the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TikTokAPI'`

My code is:

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

api = TikTokApi.get_instance()

videos_by_hashtag = api.by_hashtag(hashtag='dogs', count=5)

for video in videos_by_hashtag:
    print(video['desc'])

videos_by_hashtag = api.by_hashtag(hashtag='cats', count=5)

for video in videos_by_hashtag:
    print(video['desc'])
```

Already installed the package over
`pip install tiktokapi`

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just read that. Did you try: `pip install TikTokApi` and then 
`python -m playwright install`?

Comment: What version of python are you running on your computer?

Comment: Yes i did. Version: 3.10.8